# Ember: What is the accepted paradigm for saving data to the back-end?

Tags: model-view-controller, ember.js, console, ember-data, ember-cli

I am new to Ember and am used to the MVC model of creating controllers to move data between the view and the server. With Ember, it appears that controllers are support but there is very little documentation on them on the Ember website. From what I can tell, there is an alternative method to save data through the route. Is there an accepted paradigm for how to save data from the front-end to the back-end in Ember?

Comment: I guess it would be to use the built in [Datastore](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/ember-data/). You can use that in controller and in route (and in a component if you inject it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Ember guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/) show you how to use different alternatives.
One easy way is to use [Ember data](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/tutorial/ember-data/) to handle the rest interface with the backend.
Regarding architecture design, you can use the routes or the controllers to interact with you backend using the [store](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/models/creating-updating-and-deleting-records/).
In our projects we retrieve data in the route, and store it from the controllers.